# Manual only trigger as pre-deployment condition in yaml

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to set pre-deployment condition as 'Manual only' in specific environments in yaml?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set pre-deployment condition as 'Manual only' in
>   specific environments in yaml?

As I know the 'Manual only' condition is not supported yet in yaml pipeline, it's one option only available in classic UI pipeline for now. Though the stages in release classic pipeline and that in Yaml both supports conditions, they actually behave differently and we can't use 'manual only' in yaml.

Not sure about your expected scenario to use that option in yaml, please check if this [related discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/697467/manually-triggered-stages-in-yaml-multi-stage-pipe.html) in our User Voice forum matches your needs. If so,  the new feature which lets us mark a stage as "always start manually" is on our roadmap now. See [latest news](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/900558/view.html) from Product team.

And if the new feature above can't meet your needs well, feel free to post your [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to share your feedback about Azure Devops. Then you can share the link here and members interested in that would vote for you. More votes in that could increase its priority and the product team would consider it seriously.

Hope it helps.